# Text to be displayed with logo and footer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I placed a codeigniter code below controller.The actual result is it displays You don\'t have permission to access this page.But i want to display text  with logo and footer.Pls help me to do that. 
Controller

```
function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->is_logged_in();
    }
    function is_logged_in()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
        {

            echo 'You don\'t have permission to access this page. <a href="../index.php/login">Login</a>';  
            die();  

            //$this->load->view('login_form');
        }       
    }
```

Logo and footer:

```
<div class="span4 logo">
                   <img src="<?php echo base_url('img/logosl.png'); ?>"  style="margin-bottom:7px; margin-top:7px;"/>
             </div>

<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, for what i can see, instead printing an echo and then die, you could actually redirect to a 403 page where you can punt whatever you want :D

```
 Header("Location: $url");
```

or just include the whole page and then die.

```
 include('403page.php');
 die();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own view. You first must understand the basics. The current controller  requires a user to be logged in. The if statement:

```
 if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
```

Is just something you can use to check if someone is logged in. In most cases you use this on 'private pages' that only logged-in people can see. The rule of thumb is that you will redirect people to the login form (the part you commented out).

The best solution is to make views. CodeIgniter does NOT work with random includes, but with 'loads'. You should make a header, and a footer (I assume the logo is the header).
Then you can easy load them:

```
if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
    {
      $this->load->view('header');
      $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

Altough the best solution is to redirect the user to the login form;

```
redirect('/login/form/', 'refresh');
```

And in that controller (login controller) you load the basic data and views. Also do not use includes or headers, CodeIgniter has many 'functions' that you should use. Like the redirect and the load.